# Regular Expression To pick off HTML Page Name

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a little help to pick off the html page name from a URL.  Supposed I have a URL such as

```
http://myhost/somecontext/Logon
```

I would like to extract just the page name "Logon" without regard to the path info "http://myhost/somecontext/".

Comment: Why would anyone down vote a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could do:

```
/[^\/]+$/
```

It means all the characters at the end of the string that aren't a `/`.

See it [here](https://regex101.com/r/jfZXw9/1).

Comment: That will do it.  Thanks!